# Transaction collision for sequential insert on Google App Engine. Why?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am inserting a set of records on Google App Engine. I insert them in batch to avoid deadline exceptions.

When there is a large number of records (for example 1k) I always receive an unexpected:

> Transaction collision for entity group
>   with key
>
> datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'GroupModel',
>   u'root', _app=u'streamtomail').
>   Retrying...

This situation happen always.

In local environment instead it works without any problem.

How is it possible to have transaction collisions if I am using a sequential process and no one is using the system in the meanwhile?

Here is the code that I use for batching:

```
def deferred_worker():
 if next_chunk():
   process_chunk()
   deferred.defer(deferred_worker)
```

where in *process_chunk()* I do 50 inserts in the database

Comment: How are you inserting 1,000 entities in a batch?  There is a 500 entity limit (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits).  Post some code, and let us know if you are doing anything using deferred or tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collision is on an instance of your 'GroupModel' entity with the key name 'root'. Based on that, I'm guessing you're putting everything inside a single entity group with that as the parent. As documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keysandentitygroups.html), every entity with the same parent is in the same entity group, to which transactions are serialized. Thus, *any* concurrent updates to any entity in that group will potentially conflict with any other.

Comment: @Nick the op is saying that the process is sequential; how could a concurrent update be possible in that case?

Comment: @systempuntoout By doing multiple sequential insertions at the same time.

Comment: @Nick Are you saying that, calling inside a loop a method that updates different entities with the same parent using db.run_in_transaction , could lead to this kind of problem?

Comment: @systempuntoout Yes, that's correct - as the documentation describes, all entities with the same parent are in the same entity group, and all modifications to a single entity group are serialized.

Comment: @Nick I see, I thought contention problem would raise just with parallel tasks on the same entity group. In this case is just a list of sequential calls in tnx "entity_of_model1.put(),entity_of_model2.put(),entity_of_model3.put()"  that generates contention.

Comment: No, that won't generate contention. It's possible you _do_ have parallel tasks, though - none of the snippets you've shared indicate you're using named tasks, so a task being executed multiple times (which is allowed by the task queue) could lead to multiple chained tasks. See this post for details on how to avoid that: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/03/Task-Queue-task-chaining-done-right

Comment: @Nick I know very well that post :D; but if you look at the OP's snippet, deferred.defer is called as the last command so I do not expect errors after that (in your post you have "florb" that could potentially fork bomb the queue). Am I wrong? I do believe that, in this case, the only reason a task could be executed more than one time is when Google App Engine fails and execute again an already succeeded task. Anyway I see your point: for long running pipeline processes (where GAE have more chances to fail), it is better to name the tasks.

Comment: @systempuntoout Uncaught exceptions aren't the only thing that can cause a task to re-execute. Although rare, tasks can be executed multiple times by the task queue through no fault of your own.